# ColdFusion Proxy Server

Tags: proxy, coldfusion, cfhttp

I'm trying to create a basic proxy server so I can keep track of what my kids are doing web wise - I know there are products out there but I thought it would be an interesting exercise to write one myself.

I have the following code that kind of works but doesn't pull any images or css through - I guess because it makes another call to the remote server and gets confused

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.bbc.co.uk">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Proxy-Connection" value="keep-alive" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Language" value="en-US,en;q=0.8">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Charset" value="ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3">
</cfhttp>

<cfset html = cfhttp.FileContent />
<cfoutput>#html#</cfoutput>`
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is the resolveurl parameter of  - set it to yes/true.  This defaults to no.

What this parameter does is resolves relative paths to absolute paths automatically for you.

Now, if you want to change those paths as well, you would change them to also route through your http proxy script, but there won't be much use as you won't know much about the content regardless.

resolveurl should hook you up with what you are looking for.  cheers.

https://cfdocs.org/cfhttp  (look for resolveurl tag attribute)

Comment: Hi - I've been using that and it doesnt make much difference - I think it may be a difference between http and https and whatever protocal you come in on works but if the site then trys to get another resource on the other protocal then it doesnt work